# Matlab: Replicate legend location's 'outside' scaling behavior

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, legend

[image: Produced figure]

The preceding figure was produced by the following code:

```
hold on;
plot([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]);
plot([1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1]);
legend('foo', 'bar', 'location', 'eastoutside');
```

Re-scaling the width of the figure window causes the legend to maintain it's dimensions, while automatically scaling the plot's width to take up the extent of the remaining space:

[image: scaled figure]

When editing the position properties of the legend, the location property is changed to 'none', losing its unique scaling behavior.

Is there any way to reproduce the scaling behavior in such a way that I could resize/re-position the legend and/or use it for a non axis-legend relationship?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking for. Do you want the legend to have a custom fixed location relative to the axis that *isn't* [one of the predefined locations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.illustration.legend-properties.html#bt7bgi4-1_sep_shared-Location)?

Comment: I would like to have a custom fixed *position* (left/bottom/width/height) relative to the axis.

Comment: It is not clear from the example what is that you want to change in the default behavior of legend location property.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position of the axes and set the position of the legend relative to them. Here is an example:

```
x = -10:10;
fig  = figure(1);
plot(x,x.^2,x,x.^3);
hL = legend('foo','bar');
% setting the position to the bottom right corner of the axes:
ax = gca;
hL.Position(1:2) = [sum(ax.Position([1 3]))-hL.Position(3) ax.Position(2)];
```

To keep the position updated upon resizing of the figure you can assign the position set to the `SizeChangedFcn` property of the figure:

```
fig.SizeChangedFcn = ...
    'hL.Position(1:2) = [sum(ax.Position([1 3]))-hL.Position(3) ax.Position(2)];';
```

any resize of the figure will update the legend position.

Comment: Try resizing the figure window and you'll find that the relative position is maintained relative to the figure, not relative to the axes.  

Your proposed solution actually places the legend in normalized units, such that at the current figure dimensions it appears relative to the axes.